# CSS DIV Inline at bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 divisions to put `inline` at the `bottom`. I've no idea on how to do that... anybody can help me?

The expected output:
[image]

The codes I've tried:

```css
.feature-description
{
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left:10%;
  padding-right:10%;
}
.start-up-phase
{
  background-color: #a82327;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 13px 22px  100px;
  text-align: justify;
  width:86%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  min-height:350px;
}
.growth-phase
{
  background-color: #196b8c;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 13px 22px  110px;
  text-align: justify;
  width:86%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  min-height:450px;
}
.expansion-phase
{
  background-color: #53752f;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 13px 22px 200px;
  text-align: justify;
  width:86%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
.phase-title
{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
.phase-content
{
  padding-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row feature-description">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="start-up-phase">
      <h4 class="phase-title">
        <strong>START UP PHASE</strong>
      </h4>
      <div class="phase-content">
        Startup phase is very crucial as reseller develop their first business partners group and hands on learning about their business culture, products and other important skills with the support of the leaders. At this point, reseller will get the most from own effort and rewarded from the initial group development. 
        <?php load_helper('html'); echo br(4) ?>
        <p>
          High Margin Retail Opportunities, Personal Residual Income, Introducer Bonus and Group Placement Incentive dedicated for reseller in this phase.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="growth-phase">
      <h4 class="phase-title">
        <strong>START UP PHASE</strong>
      </h4>
      <div class="phase-content">
        Startup phase is very crucial as reseller develop their first business partners group and hands on learning about their business culture, products and other important skills with the support of the leaders. At this point, reseller will get the most from own effort and rewarded from the initial group development. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="expansion-phase">
      <h4 class="phase-title">
        <strong>START UP PHASE</strong>
      </h4>
      <div class="phase-content">
        Startup phase is very crucial as reseller develop their first business partners group and hands on learning about their business culture, products and other important skills with the support of the leaders. At this point, reseller will get the most from own effort and rewarded from the initial group development. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think, that you have to apply vertical-align:bottom to each of those divs you want to have at the bottom, but just a suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use flexbox with media queries to do this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/227/

```
@media(min-width: 1200px) {
    .row.feature-description {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
        align-items: flex-end;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me. I choose this as accepted answer.

Comment: Cool i think this is best solution for your problem.

Comment: The problem is with this approach. Flex support around browsers differs very much. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox You should test your code thoroughly in the different browsers.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox can support..I think this was enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, bootstrap use float for his grid system. So vertical-align is a bit rough to apply. 
You can chooose to use display: inline-block or display: table (with display: table-cell on childrens) to have your result.
Then you just have to specify a vertical-align: bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:inline-block` and don't forget [remove the extra spaces](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) which is occuered by `display:inline-block`

```
.col-lg-4 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    float:none;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66tc4vf6/)

Comment: I'd tried your code. Still got problem..the last block go down.

Comment: You can solve it, as I told, you should remove the extra spaces. Check [this](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) @Imran

Answer (score 1):

this fix it to go to the bottom, even with bootstrap.

```
.feature-description
{
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}
```

to make it look like a staircase you should change the `padding`

```
.start-up-phase
{
  padding: 13px 22px;
}

.growth-phase
{
  padding: 13px;
}
```

```css
.feature-description {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}
.start-up-phase {
  background-color: #a82327;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 13px 22px;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 86%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 350px;
}
.growth-phase {
  background-color: #196b8c;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 13px;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 86%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 450px;
}
.expansion-phase {
  background-color: #53752f;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 13px 22px 200px;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 86%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.phase-title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row feature-description">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="start-up-phase">
        <h4 class="phase-title"><strong>START UP PHASE</strong></h4>
        <div class="phase-content">
          Startup phase is very crucial as reseller develop their first business partners group and hands on learning about their business culture, products and other important skills with the support of the leaders. At this point, reseller will get the most from
          own effort and rewarded from the initial group development.
          <?php load_helper( 'html'); echo br(4) ?>
          <p>
            High Margin Retail Opportunities, Personal Residual Income, Introducer Bonus and Group Placement Incentive dedicated for reseller in this phase.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="growth-phase">
        <h4 class="phase-title">
        <strong>START UP PHASE</strong>
      </h4>
        <div class="phase-content">
          Startup phase is very crucial as reseller develop their first business partners group and hands on learning about their business culture, products and other important skills with the support of the leaders. At this point, reseller will get the most from
          own effort and rewarded from the initial group development.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="expansion-phase">
        <h4 class="phase-title">
        <strong>START UP PHASE</strong>
      </h4>
        <div class="phase-content">
          Startup phase is very crucial as reseller develop their first business partners group and hands on learning about their business culture, products and other important skills with the support of the leaders. At this point, reseller will get the most from
          own effort and rewarded from the initial group development.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes..it works but problems when at smaller screen size.

Comment: with media queries you can say that it should ignore the `display: flex` and `align-items: flex-end` bij setting it to `display: block` and `align.items: inherit`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to put all div's at the bottom.

```css
.feature-description
{
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left:10%;
  padding-right:10%;
  position: relative;
}
.start-up-phase, .growth-phase, .expansion-phase{
      bottom: 0;
}
```

Continue your CSS:

.start-up-phase
    {...