# Make text NOT align with sibling element text

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I don't know if the title is good enough, but I'll explain it here more thoroughly. So I've got the following HTML code:

```
<section>
    <aside>
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "col-md-4 lefterino">
                <p><span>Daily Posts</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteteur adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteteur adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteteur adipiscing elit</p>
                <p><span>Daily Posts</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteteur adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteteur adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteteur adipiscing elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-3 midderino">
                <p>asd</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-4 righterino">
                <p>asd</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
 </section>
```

And the following CSS code:

```
section {
  height: 100%; // screen height   
}

aside {
  bottom: 0em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.lefterino {
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.lefterino p {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
  opacity: 0.92;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}
```

The problem is that I want to align all the elements from the container div's at the bottom of the section. **For the first div (lefterino) it works fine**. For the second and third one, the elements (in my case the `<p>`) always gets aligned with the elements from the first div.

Here's an image that shows the effect:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995354/css-div-inline-at-bottom/33995611#33995611

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't reproduce the problem. If you can provide enough code for us to see the problem and/or a working demo (e.g., jsfiddle.net), that would be helpful.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/343/?

Comment: Thanks to the code from Nenad Vracar, I managed to fix the problem. I had to apply { display:inline-block; float: none; vertical-align: bottom; } to the div's. Thanks!